# Не получается составить регулярное выражение для выделения версии пакета

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть набор строк следующего вида:

```
'8.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), 9.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), 1.16.0 (c-ares)',
'8.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), 9.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), до 1.16.0 включительно (c-ares)',
'8.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), 1.16.0 (c-ares), 9.0 (Debian GNU/Linux)'
'8.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), от 1.15.1 до 1.16.0 (c-ares), 9.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), 10.0 (Debian GNU/Linux)',
'до 1.11.0 (c-ares), 8.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), 9.0 (Debian GNU/Linux)'
'1.11.0 (c-ares), 8.0 (Debian GNU/Linux), 9.0 (Debian GNU/Linux)'
```

Необходимо регулярным выражением вытащить версию библиотеки (в данном примере c-ares). Если версии две (как в строке 4: от 1.15.1 до 1.16.0), необходимо получить их обе. Если одна, то получить только одну.

Составленное мной выражение обрабатывает некорректно случаи, когда указана только одна версия библиотеки.

```
regex = fr'(?i)([\S.]+)?\D*?([\S.]+)?\D+?\({lib_name}\)'
```

Выражением нужно корректно получать именно две группы, чтобы знать диапазон версий. Если указана только одна версия, то одна из групп останется пустой.

*PS. Версии могут быть в любом виде: 1.2.3, 4.5, 6 или даже xyz и 31462c97*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В группы берем только нерусские символы и цифры без пробелов и запятых, окруженные русскими словами.

```
[а-яА-я ]*([^а-яА-я, ]*)[а-яА-я ]*([^а-яА-я, ]*)[а-яА-я ]*\(c-ares\)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OfnMxv/1)

Comment: Такое выражение отлично покрывает большинство случаев, спасибо! 
Однако остается вопрос как обрабатывать строки, в которых версия указана как "до 1.2.3 (включительно)". То есть подразумевается крайняя граница версии, а не начальная\единственная.

Comment: @СвятославСергеев  А если перед вытаскиванием заменить "до "с пробелом на, что-нибудь этакое "<="?

Comment: @СвятославСергеев  Правда нужно два варианта "включительно" -  не "включительно" - "<-"

Comment: так и сделал, заменил во временном фрейме "до 1.2.3" на "от 0 до 1.2.3" и их уже разобрал по регулярке, а изначальную полную строку вытащил по полученному индексу из оригинального фрейма.